# How to displace in blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, displacement

How do I displace in blender 2.8? I am used to going to the texturing tab and then changing the image in the displace texture to the proper image but the texturing tab simply says TexDraw and I cant do anything about it.

Comment: "*How do I displace in Blender 2.8?*" You wait for the full release when things are working properly and it is feature complete and ready for end users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an incomplete version of Blender

Comment: Can you show an image of what you are getting?